# Find root of a function defined as a Module

Tags: equation-solving

I have a simple module like

```
BCdet[x_, y_] := Module[
  {AuxMat},
  AuxMat = Mat /. {f -> x, A -> y};
  Det[AuxMat]
  ]
```

where `Mat` is a normal matrix 12x12 with parameters `f` and `A`. The above defined module returns a complex number and it works without any problems.

Then I would like to find root of its real part for given `A=trailA` and for a complex `f`

```
FindRoot[
 Re[BCdet[f, trialA]],
 {f, 2.5 + 0. I},
 StepMonitor :> Print["Step to f = ", f]
 ]
```

Unfortunately, this does not work at all. I cannot get any result.
I use `StepMonitor` to check it, however, it does not give any output.
Any idea where might be the problem?

Comment: But as I understood, this evaluates function only when its argument is a number. I think this must be obeyed in the example with FindRoot, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider making `Mat` a function of `f` and `A`. Or if you wish to work with your code, make sure `f` and `A` do not have values. `FindRoot` temporarily gives `f` a value in your example. Therefore in your code the replacement rule for f will be broken. However, this is usually not a problem as `f` will be given its value simply by evaluation. But it does show the risk of making a function like this. If you give `A` a value, then it does not make a difference what you set `trialA` to, as the rule for A will be broken.

Fortunately we have

```
x /. {3.3 -> 5}
```

> x

but it would be terrible if `3.3` would appear on the LHS of `/.`, as you would then get an undesired replacement . This is not what makes your code fail to work however. Consider these definitions

```
Mat2[A_, f_] := {{A + I, f}, {A + f, A + f + 3 I}}

BCdet[x_, y_] := Module[
  {AuxMat},
  AuxMat = Mat2[y,x];
  Det[AuxMat]
  ]
```

Now, for me it works if we simply do

```
FindRoot[BCdet[x, trialA], {x, 5}]
```

-> {x -> 3.01955 + 7.45469 I}

And we have

```
Abs[BCdet[3.019546672440941` + 7.454686341385149` I, trialA]]
```

> 2.99373*10^-14

Which is pretty close to 0. However, you code does not work

```
FindRoot[Re[BCdet[x, trialA]], {x, 5}]
```

--messages--> The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance...

I suppose you can leave out the `Re` as without the `Re` `FindRoot` will find a solution with a small real part anyway. But that is a bit ugly.

**Remarks**

If you wish to do still use replacement rules, at least use `HoldPattern`. But first another suggestion. If you don't want to do

```
BCdet[f_, A_] :=  Det[{{A + I, f}, {A + f, A + f + 3 I}}]
```

Because `Mat` is so big, or because you want to reuse/change Mat, you can do something like

```
Clear[A, f]

Mat = {{A + I, f}, {A + f, A + f + 3 I}};

With[
      {Mat = Mat}
      ,
      BCdet[f_, A_] :=  Det[Mat]
 ]
```

I suggest you work with regular functions so I don't have to explain everything below :P. This would make your code work but it is really inconvenient:

```
Clear[A,f]
With[
 {Mat = {{A + I, f}, {A + f, A + f + 3 I}}}
 ,
 BCdet[x_, y_] := 
  Module[{AuxMat}, 
   AuxMat = Unevaluated[Mat] /. {HoldPattern[f] -> x, HoldPattern[A] -> y};
   Det[AuxMat]]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I always use Clear[f,A]. Finally, it seems that adding `BCdet[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ]` to the definition helped. Unfortunately, I do not understand why. I guess, the arguments always must be numbers.

Comment: @LLapsus note that there is still a risk because f is given a value by `FindRoot`. You might get undesired replacements still, but it is very unlikely.